Drive geometry nodes by normal map?

I have an object, and for each vertex, I want to instance-on-points an object rotated in the normal direction specified by the normal map at that vertex's UVs. However:

Geometry nodes does not have a "Normal Map" node to convert an image texture to vectors
Geometry nodes "Image Texture" does not provide colorspaces, so I don't know if the normal map is being loaded as sRGB or linear.

If I replace the image texture with (0.5, 0.5, 1.0), I get the expected behavior of all normals pointing vertically, which makes me suspect this is a colorspace issue:

Is there a "correct" way to do this?


Solved it, I think.

Bake normal map to vertex colors (in linear color)
Add vertex colors to geometry nodes input and configure the modifier to use the right vertex colors

Let me know if there's a better way.
